# When $ y = v + 1 $ and $ x = u + 3 $, is it true that $ dy/dx = dv/du $?

Tags: derivatives, change-of-variable

Let $ y(x) $ be a function of $ x $.

Let $ u(x) = x - 3 $.

Let $ v(y) = y - 1 $.

Is it true that $ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dv}{du} $?

If yes, how can we prove it?

If not, what is a simple counterexample for it?

Comment: $\dfrac{\textrm dy}{\textrm dx}=\dfrac{\textrm dv}{\textrm du}$ is equivalent to $\dfrac{\textrm du}{\textrm dx}=\dfrac{\textrm dv}{\textrm dy}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed true that $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u}$. Notice that $\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u}=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}u}=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}$. Furthermore, $y=v+1$ implies $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}$. Thus $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u}$$

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Leibniz notation $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is confusing.  [In particular using the letter $y$ as both a function and a variable at the same time can confuse beginners.]  Let's analyze the meaning.

---

Writing $\frac{dy}{dx}$, you assume $y$ is a function of $x$.  Say $y = \phi(x)$, where $\phi$ is a function.  Then
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \phi'(x) .
$$
Next, in order to write $\frac{dv}{du}$, we need to write $v$ as a function of $u$.  We are given $u=x-3, v=y-1$.  Then we write $v$ as a function of $u$ by computing:
$$
v = y-1 = \phi(x)-1 = \phi(u+3)-1 .
$$
So
$$
\frac{dv}{du} = \frac{d}{du}\big(\phi(u+3)-1\big) = \phi'(u+3)
$$
We used the chain rule, together with the observation that both $3$ and $-1$ have derivative $0$.
Finally, in terms of $x$
$$
\frac{dv}{du} = \phi'(u+3) = \phi'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} .
$$

---

Note: Here I used the letter $x,y,u,v$ as variables, and the letter $\phi$ as a function.  I wrote $y = \phi(x)$ and did not write confusing things like $y(x), u(x), v(y), v(u)$.

Answer (score 0):

It's true

${y}={v}+\mathrm{1}\:,\:{x}={u}+\mathrm{3} \\ $
$\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}=\frac{{d}\left({v}+\mathrm{1}\right)}{{dv}}.\frac{{dv}}{{du}}.\left(\frac{{d}\left({u}+\mathrm{3}\right)}{{du}}\right)^{-\mathrm{1}} =\frac{{dv}}{{du}} \\ $